# Estimate of the norm of the gradient in $H^1(\Omega)^n$ in terms of the norm of the function in $H^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded  and $u \in H^2(\Omega).$

Does it hold that
$$
\Vert \nabla u \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)^n}^2 \leq \Vert u \Vert_{H^2(\Omega)}^2?
$$

In my attempt, I always find a constant in the right-hand side, meaning
$$
\Vert \nabla u \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)^n}^2 \leq C \Vert u \Vert_{H^2(\Omega)}^2
$$
where $C>0$.

Comment: It depends on how you define these norms. Usually $C=1$ comes directly from the definition of the norms.